# VideoView not visible if height is WRAP_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview

I have a videoview inside my app, it is a small videoview, is not fullscreen.

Doing this i got a non visible videoView:

```
mVideo.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

mVideo.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mVideo.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getIntWidth(), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                }
            });
```

and doing this i got a perfectly visible videoView:

```
mVideo.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 1));

mVideo.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mVideo.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getIntWidth(), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                }
            });
```

Why i have to put 1 pixel of heigh in the initial height size of the videoview?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you're using it for video, wrap_content has no content to wrap until you start playing a video .

The view doesn't yet know the size of the content, since the content haven't been added yet, so it can't wrap it either.

The 1 px height let the view to draw .

Comment: Yes, setting the `width` and `height` to `match_parent` work fine, and with `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` perfect.